# killAnonymous not working as expected for anonymous proxy

Tags: pallet, proxy

I have created an anonymous proxy(Proxy pallet). Now I need to delete this `proxy`.
I am using killAnonymous but it is giving me errors.
[image]

Please suggest what i am doing incorrect here

Comment: I believe the extrinsic was executed successfully. The "incomplete execution" error seems like a misleading message.

Can you check in storage that the proxy account has been removed?

Comment: The only error that can be returned by `killAnonymous` is `NoPermission`, otherwise, it cannot fail.

Comment: Yeah it's not deleted from the storage

Comment: When you generated the anonymous account, did you give yourself full permissions? Otherwise, you won't be able to delete the account.

Comment: yeah, I created one proxy with Any and the other with Non-Transfer Proxy Type. and deleting the Non-transfer with Any One.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand. Can add to your question how I can reproduce the issue locally? And maybe also what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `kill_anonymous` call needs to come [from the anonymous itself](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/c9fc99d/frame/proxy/src/lib.rs#L368L372):

```rust
let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;
let when = (height, ext_index);
let proxy = Self::anonymous_account(&spawner, &proxy_type, index, Some(when));
ensure!(proxy == who, Error::<T>::NoPermission);
```

Of course the only way to access an anonymous proxy origin is via `proxy.proxy`. Your call above is correct, but you need to wrap it in a `proxy.proxy` such that the origin is the anon proxy.

```javascript
proxy.proxy(
    real: <YOUR_ANON_PROXY>,
    force_proxy_type: Any,
    call: proxy.killAnonymous(
        /* args */
    )

)
```

This is because the spawner may have set a new account as the proxy and removed itself, so the permission to kill an anon rests with the anon itself.